# Sub menu jumping up once clicked?

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

We have a oddly coded sub menu that was customized so it could be in a specific column setup, however when you click a link under that sub menu, the sub menu then jumps up while the next page is loading. It looks pretty bad :P

For example when you go here: goo.gl/4mW5sW

and hover over the menu item "All discs" you can see the dropdown with the 2 customized columns.

If you click one of these links you will see the drop down than jump up while the page loads the link you clicked.

I have been combing through the css trying to locate why it jumps with an active click and am having no luck. Maybe another pare of eyes will help?

I even tried this pathetic attempt

a:active .sub-menu{display:none;}
But it didnt help

Thanks!

Comment: i am not able to replicate your bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the margin-top and the hover state of the `ul class="sub-menu'`. Find a way to select only the first column and add the next css:
    `margin-top: -1px!important;`

Then select only the second column and add the next css:
    `margin-top: -1px!important;`

You are giving both colums a -71px as `top-margin` and when hover is toggled you mess that margin for the first column, giving it a -71px of top margin.
If you provide code, i can help you further

Comment: I'm not really sure what code you're asking for? I would love further help.

Comment: .main-navigation ul.menu ul.sub-menu > .custom-dropdown1 > ul li ul:first-of-type {
    margin-top: -71px!important;
    padding-top: 0px;
}

What do i replace it with? since if the -71px isnt there, when you hover it shows the UL too far down